# What name restrictions do exist for attributes that are used with &-binding in Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the following code I use the attribute **selected** for a callback from a directive to its parent controller.

I noticed that when I change selected to something like setSelected or XXXSelected (the prefix doesn't seem to matter), then the corresponding method on the parent controller never gets called, as outlined in the comments.

Apparently, this collides with some other concept I don't know of yet and I assume I cannot use XXXSelected as attribute name. Is that correct? If so, what other restrictions do exist on naming?

('set' is in object in my problem domain, not meant to be a method or setter)

**parent.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="set in parentCtrl.sets">
    <my-directive set="set" selected="parentCtrl.setSelected(set)"></my-directive>
    <!-- this would not work: my-directive set="set" XXXSelected="parentCtrl.setSelected(set)"></my-directive -->
</div>
```

**parent.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function () {
this.setSelected = function(set) {

  // does not get called when replacing selected with XXXSelected
  console.log(set.someAttribute);
};

  });
```

**set.html**

```
<div ng-click="setCtrl.select()"> … </div>
```

**set.directive.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {

    function SetCtrl($scope) {

      this.select = function() {

        console.log($scope.selected); // reports: function(locals)
        $scope.selected({set: $scope.set});

        //console.log($scope.XXXSelected); // also reports: function(locals)
        //$scope.XXXSelected({set: $scope.set}); //would not get called
      }

    }

    return {

      templateUrl: 'set.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: SetCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'setCtrl',
      scope: {
        selected: '&',
        //XXXSelected: '& // this would not work
      }

    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with:

```
<my-directive set="set" x-x-x-selected="parentCtrl.setSelected(set)"></my-directive>
```

Angular splits in HTML with a `-` where in JavaScript there is a CamelCase.
So if you would name your JS-Property `myAttributeLooksLikeThis`, you would use `my-attribute-looks-like-this=""` in your html. This is due to the Case-Insensitivity of HTML Tags.

You can also read about this in the official Docs about Directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)